# Accumulate value loop

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1

I am new to Python and currently trying to get my first script to work. Could someone tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
total = 0
def accumulate(increment):
 global total
 if total:
  if (total >= 1103):
    total = (total - 1103)
   else:
    total += increment
 else:
    total = increment
 return total
```

This one (the example from ESRI) works:

```
total = 0
def accumulate(increment):
 global total
 if total:
  total += increment
 else:
  total = increment
 return total
```

I am trying to run this code in ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Your indentation on the first **else** does not seem to line up with the second **if**.  If you use IDLE or another Python IDE to author your scripts it should take care of indentation automatically.  Also, can you show us where you are calling your accumulate function from and any errors you are receiving, please?

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you PolyGeo! So simple... [edit] Ah, didn't see your edit.. I am calculating this inside the Field Calculator that loops through a List. Here is the call: accumulate( !WeaSMax_W! ) I just tried to find a way to skip accumulation of a field when a value is reached. It works now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation on the first **else** does not seem to line up with the second **if**.

If you use IDLE or another Python IDE to author/test your scripts it should take care of indentation automatically.

You can then copy/paste them into the Field Calculator knowing that your Python syntax is right.

Comment: Finally I decided for PyScripter. Much better than Notepad++ for Phyton Code writing! Thanks for the hint.